# Creating Blob in Azure Blob Storage with the same name simultaneously

Tags: c#, azure, blob

I have task to load some images into the blob storage simultaneously. Name of blob is defined as md5 of the blob. It can happen that different threads try to load same files from different locations.

Now I need to know how to block other threads from loading same file, if first already trying to upload such blob.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it without leasing it by using optimistic concurrency. Basicly set an access condition that says this blob will be different from all etags of blobs with this name. If there is indeed a blob with some etag the second upload will fail.

```
var access = AccessCondition.GenerateIfNoneMatchCondition("*");
await blobRef.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream, access, null, null);
```

Comment: What would happen if the blob does not exist and two processes start to upload the same file simultaneously? If I am not mistaken, for this particular access condition the blob must be present in the storage.

Comment: It must certainly not be present in storage. We are using this method currently. If I understand the azure storage correctly, both processes will upload the data. At the end, a manifest is uploaded combining several parts under a blob name. This is an atomic operation and only one of the calls will succeed.

Comment: Thanks. I have never tried it thus I was curious. In your scenario, you're splitting a blob into blocks and uploading those blocks. Have you tried it with a scenario where blob is really small and thus not broken into parts?

Comment: I assume the API handles all this for me, but again I could be mistaken. We are using very small blobs also and they seem to work the same way.